# Add prefix and suffix to all lines in all files?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command

I have a huge list of text files in one of my folders - in each text file is a list of domain names.

I need to add this before each line:

```
<url><loc>http://www.mysite.com/review/
```

And this at the end of each line:

```
</url></loc>
```

Is there any way to massive do this on all the files and all the lines at once through command line?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
sed 's@^@<url><loc>http://www.mysite.com/review/@; s@$@</url></loc>@' files*.html
```

Add the `-i` switch to `sed` if you want to replace the files in place.

Comment: It output all of it in SSH correctly but didn't make the changes to the actual files.

Comment: That means you forgot the `-i` option.

Comment: Equivalently, `s/.*/foo&bar/` to add the prefix `foo` and the suffix `bar` to all lines.